# How to split JHipster generated project into multi module gradle project

Tags: gradle, jhipster

I am trying to split Jhipster generated project into multi module project.
I want to separate Presentation layer with angularJs into separate module. 
How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

However, with a little effort you can separate the **deployment** of frontend and backend. i.e. use nginx for the frontend contents (configured to proxy the requests to the backend) and use tomcat for the backend.

i.e. change the dist directory and then do "grunt build". A few things will be missing (init, bower_components and i18n). aka, editing a bit the Gruntfile.js will be required in order to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

JHipster is not meant to be a "multi-module" project.
Of course you can do it if you want to re-code everything, but that would be really complicated.